# How to form subset form a set of numbers in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

Dear Netlogo community,

I am looking to generate subset of a set of numbers. 
for example if a set is [1 2 3 4 5] then subset would be [1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [1 5] [ 1 2 3] [1 2 4]....... I know we can generate very easily by using bit manipulation in java. But I have no idea how to implement in Netlogo. I am doomed. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is easiest to solve using recursion:

```
to-report subsets [xs]
  if empty? xs [ report [[]] ]
  let recurse subsets butfirst xs
  report sentence recurse
                  map [fput first xs ?] recurse
end
```

The basic idea is that if you want the subsets of `[1 2 3]`, first you find all the subsets of `[2 3]`. All of them are themselves subsets of `[1 2 3]`, plus if you stick the `1` on the front of each of them, the resulting lists are part of the answer too.

sample run:

```
observer> print subsets [1 2 3]
[[] [3] [2] [2 3] [1] [1 3] [1 2] [1 2 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem with above mentioned code is that it gives the subset of up to 21 elements in a list.  on 22nd element it throws message of java heap space out of memeory. I tried to increase the allocation of RAM for java but it didnt resolve the issue. looking for your valuable feedback. Thanks

Comment: I see you've opened a new question on this at http://stackoverflow.com/q/31019305/86485